# Read varchar as a char array

Tags: java, database, type-conversion, mybatis

Is it possible to read data from a database column of type varchar as a char array in java?

I must add that I'm using MyBatis. So far my internet trawling hasn't brought anything up.

Answer (score 4):

Why can't you read it as a `String` and then convert into a `char[]`?

```
char[] chars = rs.getString("VARCHAR_COLUMN").toCharArray();
```

Comment: That would be fine if I was using straight jdbc, but it's not so straight forward as I'm using MyBatis as my data access layer.

Comment: but since you have DAL, it seems almost impossible to me that there's no place available to do this conversion... ?

Comment: I was just checking the documentation of MyBatis. Seems like you can [write a typehandler and use it in the resultmap](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s05.html).

Comment: @Less yes I do have a DAL but MyBatis sets the values directly on the DAOs. I need a way to intercept this.

Comment: @adarshr yes, I have considered type handlers, however if you read the following link you'll notice that they're now generised so I cant convert between types. Also type handlers override for all database types. http://www.mybatis.org/core/configuration.html#typeHandlers

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to provide an implementation of SqlSessionDaoSupport and use a ResultHandler to transform the string data into a char array to be stored within the simple POJO.

This doesn't provide the perfect solution, as I'd like to read the data from the database as a char array and never have a string constructed. However, this is a good step in the right direction.